# Issues with Date field in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working with some existing code. There are 3 fields that use the *JavaScript date picker* and set it as a `java.util.Date` to the bean.

I added a new field called `reportPeriod(java.util.Date)`. When I read this date in the debugger it is of type `"Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014"`. When doing a *Save* on the screen, the `bindingPreparation` method is done. Here all the fields that are of type `java.util.Date` are bound. Since the 3 date fields were set by the JavaScript , they are all of the form `"mm/dd/yyyy"`. The `bindingPreparation` method takes these dates as Strings and tries to parse them. It fails for the report period date.

I would like to be able to take this String `"Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014"` and convert it into it corresponding date of format `mm/dd/yyyy`. I tried using `SimpleDateFormat` but doesnt work.

My other option was to make this a `java.sql.Date`, so that it doesnt go through the binding preparation method. However, the issue that arises is that I am passing this report period as a hidden field and I get an error saying that *cannot convert string to date*.

This is how I have my hidden field: I passed `reportPeriodDate` from the controller by adding it to the model view.

```
<input type="hidden" name="companyLot[${Index.index}].reportPeriodDate" value="${reportPeriodDate}"/>
```

Update:
The Binding method is as follows:

```
    @InitBinder
   public void bindingPreparation(WebDataBinder binder){


    CompCustomDateEditor customDateEditor=new CompCustomDateEditor();
    binder.registerCustomEditor(java.util.Date.class, customDateEditor);
```

This CompCustomDateEditor was written by someone else, who assumed that all the dates would be entered from javascript using a datepicker of type dd/mm/yyyy. All that this cutomDateEditor does is splits the date up into month year date and then creates the date using format yyyy-mm-dd. So the reason my code is failing is it try to parse this string "Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014". Hence I would like to somehow make this string to 07/31/2014. Not sure how though.

Here is the customDateEditor

```
 public class CompCustomDateEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {     
 public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if(!StringUtility.isNullOrEmpty(text))
    {

        StringTokenizer str=new StringTokenizer(StringUtility.trim(text),"/");
        StringBuffer dateString=new StringBuffer();


        while(str.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            dateString=dateString.append(str.nextToken());

        }
        StringBuffer dateStringNew=new StringBuffer();
        String tmp = dateString.substring(4,8).replace(",","");
        //dateStringNew=dateStringNew.append(dateString.substring(4,8));
        dateStringNew=dateStringNew.append(tmp);
                dateStringNew.append("-");
                dateStringNew.append(dateString.substring(0, 2));
                dateStringNew.append("-");
                String monthStr = dateString.substring(2, 4);
                //dateStringNew.append(dateString.substring(2, 4));
                dateStringNew.append(monthStr);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


        try {

            //java.util.Date customDate=dateFormat.parse(dateString.toString());
            java.util.Date customDate=dateFormat.parse(dateStringNew.toString());
            setValue(customDate);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `bindingPreparation()`? Where is it? Can you show more code? The controller and that method maybe?

Comment: This is binding method:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is to set *reportPeriodDate* in a model as a string that is recognized by your *bindingPrepartion* method, `SimpleDateFormat` most definitely works for this, note that you should use a capitalized `M`, lower-cased refers to minutes. So if your *reportPeriodDate* is of type `java.util.Date`, convert it to appropriate string and add it to model, e.g.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String stringReportPeriodDate = dateFormat.format(reportPeriodDate)
```

if even in a controller is a string, than first convert to Date and than format to appropriate format e.g.

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date reportPeriodDate =formatter.parse("Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014")
```

or as you said in the comments, just add an if branch in your custom editor, something like

```
   if(text.length() >10){
     DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
     Date date=formatter.parse(text);
     setValue(date);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. That is what I was trying to do. I set the String as : String rptPeriodStr ="07/31/2014". Then used SimpleDateFormat and tried to get the Date. The date is now "Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014". This is then trying to get parsed in the customdateeditor.

Comment: The report period date for me always is null as it is failing the binding preparation- with an unparsable date "Jul-Th-u". My other option is to update the customdate editor to check if the text size is > 10 ie it is not of the format MM/dd/yyyy. If it isnt then change the Jul 31 string to be of type 07/31/2014. I dont know how to do this.

Comment: yes, additional if check is viable solution, I've edited the answer

Comment: I am getting "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jul 31 00:00:00 EDT 2014"" error. Any idea

Comment: Corrected the format, should be fine now, added EEE for day

Answer (score 0):

1. Be careful when using hidden input fields, as users can always change the value
2. Use the [`@DateTimeFormat`](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/08/using-spring-3-datetimeformat.html#.VR2UQPnmrmE) annotation on date fields in your POJOs, and use Spring's form tag:

   ```
   public class Foo {

     @DateTimeFormat( ... )
     private Date reportPeriodDate;

     ...
   }
   ```

   `<form:hidden path="..." />`
3. Use the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) date/time format for transport and storage (and UTC time zone for storage if using times)
4. Use the HTML5 date picker if you can
5. The long datetime string you are seeing when debugging is probably the result of calling toString() on a Date object, and probably isn't the value that the client is sending to the server

Comment: Thanks. I agree your idea seems the right approach- will keep it in mind when we re write.